# Proving in Quine's New Foundations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, foundations

I'm reading Quine's New Foundations paper. However, there are a lot of questions I do not manage to answer. I would say they all lead to the question: how to prove things in NF? For example, is it provable in NF that

$\forall x (x \in \{x\})$

or commutativity of identity, being this latter defined as

$x = y \stackrel{def}{=} \forall w (x \in w \rightarrow z \in w)$

and finally how do you prove - if possible - that

$x = y \wedge z \in x \rightarrow z \in y$

with just the axioms and definitions Quine provides in his paper?

I came up with these questions in connection with something Quine says in his paper. He says that the "unrestricted" abstraction principle

$\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi)$

for $x$ not occurring in $\phi$, provides a class $x$ about which he says "viz. $\widehat{y} \phi$". Now, I think this means that from the abstraction principle you can prove $\widehat{y}\phi$ for any $\phi$ of the required kind, is it so? I do not even manage to prove that

$x = y \rightarrow x \subset y \wedge y \subset x$

Comment: I think you mean $x = y \land \color{red}{x} \in z \to y \in z$

Comment: Are you sure about your definition of identity?

Comment: See D11 and D12: Quine defines (as usual): $\{ \alpha \} = \text {the class of all objects } \beta \text { such that } \beta=\alpha$. In modern terms: $\{ \alpha \} = \{ \beta \mid \beta = \alpha \}$. Obviously: $\alpha = \alpha$; thus $\alpha \in \{ \alpha \}$.

Comment: The "unrestricted" abstraction principle is the well-known [(unrestricted) axiom schema of comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension): it asserts that "for every formula $\phi$ with (at least) one free var $y$ there is the *class* of all and only those $y$ such that $\phi$ holds of them, i.e. $\{ y \mid \phi \}$." It leads to [Russell's paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/).

Comment: To @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you. However, I would like to see a proof using axioms and rules of this. How do you pass from $a = a$ to $a \in \{a\}$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the proof would be (for what we said in the commentaries to the other answer): $a = a \stackrel{def}{=} \forall x (a \in x \rightarrow a \in x) \Rightarrow (a \in \widehat{x}(x = a) \rightarrow a \in \widehat{x}(x = a)) \Rightarrow (a = a \rightarrow a \in \widehat{x}(x=a))$, and since $\vdash a = a$ from the extensionality principle, $\vdash a \in \widehat{x}(x = a)$. Can this work as a proof?

Comment: It is not true that x = y implies x $\subset$ y because x is not  proper subset of y.

Comment: yes I mean indeed $x = y \rightarrow x \subseteq y \wedge y \subseteq x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove in [$\mathsf {NF}$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2300564?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) the full set of properties of *equality*, we need both:

> D8. $(a=b) \text { for } (\forall x)((a \in x) \to (b \in x))$,

and *extensionality*:

> P1. $((x \subseteq y) \to ((y \subseteq x) \to (x = y)))$.

From the definition of *inclusion*:

> D7. $(a \subseteq b) \text { for } (\forall x)((x \in a) \to (x \in b))$,

we get: $a \subseteq a$, and applying P1 we get:

> 1) $a=a$.

From D8, using the *abstraction* operator (for Quine, using the [Principia Mathematica's notation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/): $\hat x \phi(x)$; in modern terms: $\{ x \mid \phi(x) \}$) , we get:

> $(a=b) \to (a \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}) \to (b \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \})$

and thus:

> 2)  $(a=b) \to (\varphi(a) \to \varphi(b))$.

Now we can play with $\varphi$ to get:

> $(a=b) \to ((a=c) \to (b=c))$,
>
> $((a=b) \land (b=c)) \to (a=c)$,

and:

> 3) $(a=b) \to (b=a)$.

Now, all the expected rules for *equality* are in place.

From 2) we get: $(a=b) \to ((a \in c) \to (b \in c))$, as well as: $(a=b) \to ((c \in a) \to (c \in b))$.

Using 3) we conclude with:

> $(a=b) \to (\forall x) ((x \in a) \leftrightarrow (x \in b))$.

From *extensionality* we have:

> $((\forall x) ((x \in a) \leftrightarrow (x \in b)) \to (a=b))$,

and thus we finally have:

> > $(a=b) \leftrightarrow (\forall x) ((x \in a) \leftrightarrow (x \in b))$.

---

Reagarding the *singleton* we have, by definition of *inclusion*: $\{ x \} \subseteq a \leftrightarrow (\forall y) (y \in \{ x \} \to y \in a)$, and using the definition of *singletion* $\{ x \} = \{ z \mid z=x \}$ and the fact that $y \in \{ z \mid z=x \} \leftrightarrow (y=x)$, we get:

> $\{ x \} \subseteq a \leftrightarrow (\forall y) (y =x \to y \in a)$.

From *equality*, we have that: $\phi(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall y)((y = x) \to \phi(y))$, and thus:

> $\{ x \} \subseteq a \leftrightarrow (x \in a)$.

But: $\{ x \} \subseteq \{ x \}$, and thus:

> > $x \in \{ x \}$.

Comment: thanks for this very helpful answer. I now see that my problem is that I have not understood how to use the abstraction operator - i.e. the passage leading from D8 to 2). First, it is not clear to me whether you use the abstraction

$\widehat{x}\phi$

or the abstraction principle

$\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi)$.

However, once it has been proved that

$x = y \wedge z \in x \rightarrow z \in y$

it should be easy to prove that the abstraction principle above allows one to prove

$\widehat{y}\phi$

for any $\phi$. Is it so?

Comment: Remark: following Quine's definition of $\widehat{x}\phi$ - I am not sure whether correctly - I take $\widehat{x}\phi$ to be $\exists z (\forall x(x \in z \leftrightarrow \phi) \wedge \forall y (y = z \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in y \leftrightarrow \phi))$. Now $\exists x \forall y(y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi) \vdash \exists z (\forall y(y \in z \leftrightarrow \phi) \wedge \forall x (x = z \leftrightarrow \forall y(y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi))$ in first-order logic.

Comment: @Antpicc - the meaning of the abstarction operator must be: $a \in \hat x \phi \leftrightarrow (\exists z)( (a \in z) \land (\forall x)(x \in z \leftrightarrow \phi))$.

Comment: Ok perfect...then when I have $\forall x (a \in w \rightarrow b \in w)$ I can instantiate the $x$ in $\widehat{x}\phi$, thus $a \in \widehat{x}\phi \rightarrow b \in \widehat{x}\phi$, from which I obtain $\phi(a) \rightarrow \phi(b)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Addition: indeed, thanks to the abstraction principle we have that $a \in \widehat{x}\phi \leftrightarrow \phi(a)$. From left to right we do not need the abstraction principle, but from right to left it seems to me one cannot do without...understood that $a \in \widehat{x}\phi$ means $\exists z (a \in z \wedge \forall x(x \in z \leftrightarrow \phi))$

Comment: thanks for the answer regarding the singleton...would you say that my proof above (the sixth answer relative to the first group of commentaries) could work as well? It seems to me some ideas are in common

Comment: @Correct: from $∀w (a∈w → b∈w)$, instantiating $w$, we get $a∈  \hat x \phi x → b∈  \hat x \phi x$. An this in turn is equiv to: $\phi (a) \to \phi (b)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I wonder whether there is some proof-theoretic treatment of NF